# It is not possible to import JS package BigDecimal inside ObservableHQ

Tags: javascript, observablehq

I'm playing around with [ObservableHQ](https://observablehq.com) and decided to use the [BigDecimal package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-big-decimal). But as I use the require function to make it available I get the following feedback:

[image: error feedback]

I tried to follow the instructions in the [Introduction to require](https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/introduction-to-require) and debug it with the [Module require debugger](https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/module-require-debugger) but I'm new to JavaScript, that information wasn't of much help.

I'm running it in Firefox 75.0 in Ubuntu 18.04.

Why can't I import the package? Is this a problem with my setup or a particular condition of the package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import it using require and big-decimal for the web

```
bigDecimal = await require('js-big-decimal/dist/web/js-big-decimal.min.js').catch(
  () => window.bigDecimal
)
```

https://github.com/royNiladri/js-big-decimal#usage